# Where can I find a list of working Microsoft Graph endpoints for Sharepoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph

Where can I find a list of working REST API endpoints for Sharepoint Online? To my understanding, once things changed from 'Beta' to 'v1.0', it negated a lot of things including the '/_api/' path.

`DEBUG|{"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#sites","value":[]}`

Comment: Are you asking about the SharePoint REST API or are you asking about the SharePoint Online operations in the Microsoft Graph?

Comment: I'm asking about the Sharepoint Online REST API operations in Microsoft Graph. Graph is the new authentication mechanism for SPO, so you can't work without it.

Comment: I use the SharePoint REST API (not the Microsoft Graph) just about every day to build applications that communicate with SharePoint. I don't have any issue using the Graph, it just doesn't make sense to use it with the kind of applications I'm building. Also, at the moment, the operations exposed by the Graph for SharePoint are very limited when compared to the native SharePoint REST API.

Comment: Thanks Rob. Yea, I might have a pretty serious issue then. I saw at some point, the Sharepoint Online beta API was allowing a lot of REST API calls, but v1.0 seemed to have dropped it in favor of ADAL JS to my understanding.

Comment: You are confusing the service (Microsoft Graph) and the library used to call the service (ADAL.js in this case). The Graph was and still is a RESTful service, that hasn't changed regardless of whether you're calling the Beta or the v1.0 endpoint.

Comment: I see. Didn't realize, thanks. I guess I'm getting confused with the available documentation because I realized the Sharepoint sites are actually O365 groups and that has a separate URI entirely to which I might have to post a new question: https://dev.office.com/blogs/GroupsRESTAPI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complete list is located here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx

Use the navigation on the left to choose which object category you'd like to get endpoints for. Its relatively identical to SP '13/'16.

Comment: Thanks Oxossi. Are we sure this list is valid for the current Sharepoint Online implementation as they're using '/_api/' in their initial path? I thought this was removed from v1.0 of the SPO REST API.

Comment: The path & endpoints haven't changed for SPO - test it out.

Comment: I have and I'm still not receiving any actual content. It appears all of my error messages went away, but the DEBUG line at the top is what I receive as a response. I have a Header set to 'Accept' 'application/json;odata=verbose' so I believe the parsing should be valid. Here's the query I used: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<tenant>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists(guid'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx')`